# How to customize the testNG result console output in order to provide more information (e.g url test report)??

Tags: java, testng

I would like to know what would be the best way to customize the output showed in console after executing my tests. My main motivation is to show the report's url in the summary and be able to click and open it.
Just to mention that I am pretty new with TestNG.
Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own [reporter](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-reporters) with your own business logic:

As example, you can customize the default reporter: https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/TextReporter.java